# Documentation for default configuration for MapReduce jobs

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

It is stated in books that default input format for MapReduce jobs is TextInputFormat. I cannot find any official documentation that lists the default configuration for MapReduce jobs. It is not available in Job or Mapper class documentation.
I request for reference to some documentation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a page for some default configuration values:

- http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml

The default value for the input format is actually defined in the code (if a configuration value hasn't been set, the fall back or default is TextInputFormat, as can be seen in JobContext class, Line 185 (for v1.2.1):

- http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hadoop/common/tags/release-1.2.1/src/mapred/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/JobContext.java?view=markup